# ManualTrigger in Azure WebJob without outputting to queue at end

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

In my Visual Studio project I've created a WebJob that runs on a schedule (once a week) to dump logs from the db to blob storage. This works great but all the code is in a ManualTrigger method that has a queue message as a required output. I really have no need of this message so I'd rather not create it and have the queue sitting there growing with unused messages.

Am I understanding this correctly or is this queue message for something else and automatically removed? I can't seem to find any documentation on the generated ManualTrigger method.

My ManualTrigger code looks like:

```
[NoAutomaticTrigger]
public static void ManualTrigger(TextWriter log, int value, [Queue("queue")] out string message)
{
    ... Log Dump Code ...

    message = "Unused message";
}
```

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need queue output, don't use it :) Just remove the last parameter and you should be good to go

Comment: Lol, duh. I totally assumed the parameters were required. Thanks Victor!